# Как ограничить просмотр некоторых страниц группе пользователей WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите как лучше ограничить доступ к определенным страницам группе пользователей?
Например пользователи с группой сотрудник не могут видеть страницы магазин, заказы.

Comment: User Role Editor: это бесплатный плагин, который позволяет настраивать роли пользователей и их права доступа к контенту на вашем сайте.

Comment: Речь о Wooocommerce? "Страница магазин" доступна всем, даже не авторизованным. Иначе никто ничего купить не сможет. Она не в админке, а на фронте. Наверняка имеется что-то другое. Что именно?